# I'm using Jquery countdown for a timer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need the form to be submitted at the end of the count down. I am aware of expiryURL, but the form doesnt get processed. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Some code would help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with just a combination of classic javascript with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   setTimeout($("#myForm").submit(), 60 * 100);
});
```

This will trigger every 60 seconds (60 seconds * 100 = milliseconds), submitting the form.

HTH

Comment: Hi Benny, figured out an easier way using the plugin itself.

$('#demotimer').countdown({until: 5,layout:'{hnn} : {mnn} : {snn}', onExpiry: finishOff}); 
 function finishOff(){
$("#demo").submit();
 }

Comment: Just to make sure you're aware, the method I mentioned requires no plugins...just jQuery.  That reduces the overhead of including a library to do more than you need (maybe not)